# Regex for dollar currency format

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to check if the value is valid dollar currency

e.g 12,123,212.00

- It should accept "," as per the dollar format XXX,XXX,XXX
- Should accept only one decimal, only two digit after decimal
- Value can also be without "," e.g 12123212.00

Comment: What have you tried what is not working?

Comment: can you try tish `^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$` ..

Comment: I tried this /^[0-9]\d*(((,\d{3}){1})?(\.\d{0,2})?)$/
but it is working only for one "," e.g it is validating 12,345 but not 123,456,678

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor It doesn't throw an error for 7898787,787 not sure if it is the acceptable case in dollar format

Comment: one more `^\$?((\d{1,3})(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,1}|(\d{1})(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,2}|(\d{1,7}))(\.\d{1,2})?$` .. i think it work

Comment: not sure if you want to do it in a regex specifically - but if you are open to just using a JS function check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: You may use: `/^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/gm`

Comment: which one ? first or second example ?

Comment: @HolyMoly Yeah, actually i want to validate the string whether string is valid or not

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor Second one working for my requirement

Comment: @Deepak can i put as an answer ?

Comment: You can also try this one: ^(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{0,2})?$

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ...

```
 ^\$?((\d{1,3})(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,1}|(\d{1})(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,2}|(\d{1,7}))(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regex to validate your input then you may consider:

```
/^\$?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/re6o6D/1)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers miss your requirement `Value can also be without "," e.g 12123212.00`

So I think you should go with:

`^(\d+|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})+)\.\d{2}$`

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/FkWLjr/3

Feel free to overload the syntax with non capturing groups if the capturing groups bother you.

If you want to allow amounts without decimal parts, just change `\.\d{2}$` to `(\.\d{2})?$`.